# Getting JSON object sometimes crashes the application

Tags: android

This is my code for getting JSON Array:

```
    public void download_vse_igralce(View view)
{
    mylist.clear();  //sem dal v oklepaje
    String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
     InputStream is = null;
    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gregor-apps.com/ubs/pokazi_vse_igralce.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try{
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", ime: "+json_data.getString("ime")+
                            ", priimek: "+json_data.getString("priimek")+
                            ", pozicija: "+json_data.getString("pozicija")
                            );

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("id",  json_data.getString("id"));                    
                    map.put("firstname",  json_data.getString("ime"));                     
                    map.put("lastname",  json_data.getString("priimek"));   
                    map.put("position",  json_data.getString("pozicija"));  
                    map.put("height",  json_data.getString("height"));  
                    map.put("weight",  json_data.getString("weight"));  
                    map.put("hometown",  json_data.getString("hometown"));  
                    map.put("birthdate",  json_data.getString("birthdate"));    
                    map.put("jersey",  json_data.getString("number"));  
                    map.put("picture",  json_data.getString("slika"));
                    mylist.add(map);

            }
            downloadani_igralci=1;


    }

    }catch(JSONException e){
        downloadani_igralci=0;
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    } 
    settings(view);
}
```

In general this code works great and it returns Mylist as I want it.. But from time to time, when I call my function download_vse_igralce() the application stops to react(In most cases when i have a weak internet connection). I searched the net for async thread(or something like that), but I do not know how to implementit in this code. I there a way that the user could see a progress bar, when loading?

Comment: You are not supposed to do network requests on UI thread.
Search for AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
public void download_vse_igralce(View view){
  mylist.clear(); 
  JSONParserTask task = new JSONParserTask();
  task.execute();
}

private class JSONParserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  protected Void doInBackground( Void... ignoredParams ) {
    String result = "";
//the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));
 InputStream is = null;
//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gregor-apps.com/ubs/pokazi_vse_igralce.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

//parse json data
try{
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", ime: "+json_data.getString("ime")+
                        ", priimek: "+json_data.getString("priimek")+
                        ", pozicija: "+json_data.getString("pozicija")
                        );

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("id",  json_data.getString("id"));                    
                map.put("firstname",  json_data.getString("ime"));                     
                map.put("lastname",  json_data.getString("priimek"));   
                map.put("position",  json_data.getString("pozicija"));  
                map.put("height",  json_data.getString("height"));  
                map.put("weight",  json_data.getString("weight"));  
                map.put("hometown",  json_data.getString("hometown"));  
                map.put("birthdate",  json_data.getString("birthdate"));    
                map.put("jersey",  json_data.getString("number"));  
                map.put("picture",  json_data.getString("slika"));
                mylist.add(map);

        }
        downloadani_igralci=1;


}

}catch(JSONException e){
    downloadani_igralci=0;
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
} 
  }

  protected void onPostExecute( Void array ) {
    settings(view);
  }

}
```

Comment: asynchTask doesn't solve the problem with the unreachable network though, even if the connection is good. I'm getting exception from time to time accessing the well-known google's GeoCoder-service

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem is that you have three separate try/catch blocks, but you don't stop processing once you actually catch an exception. For instance you first do a POST, and if it fails, you then try to read the output anyway. Instead, you should `return;` in the catch block so you stop processing.

AsyncTasks are also good, and required as of 4.0, but not the solution to your problem. You should look into that as well.

Comment: Try/catch blocks do not matter, actually. Long operation (network request) on UI thread is what's causing the app to stop responding.

Comment: AsyncTask's are never required. Doing network operations off the UI thread is required as of 3.0.

Comment: Does the three seperated try/catch block make any difference? I thought that it only prevent application from crashing(for example if the first one doesn't work, then the other two won't work either - but it won't crash the application). Thank you for so quick responses to my questions - I am new to this stuff...

Comment: @BojanRadivojevicBomber well, in the question he states that the application "stops" not "stops responding" (getting an ANR). But yes, it will also block the UI. 

Gregor: Maybe you should look into how try/catch works. Yes, it stops the crash from happening, but the logic flow will continue. It also matters WHAT you catch (in the last catch you are only catching a JSON exception, not a null pointer exception, for example), it's a lengthy subject. In this case, the WHOLE code should be wrapped in a try/catch exception to prevent "rogue" exceptions to crash your code.

Comment: @dmon But also in his description of the problem, he says, quote: "... the application stops to react ...", which means - ANR

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be because of internet connection. sometimes your application could not download JSON content properly so when it is trying to parse , it is going to error state and crashing of your application is for improper style of try-catch

Answer (score 0):

"asynchTask doesn't solve the problem with the unreachable network though, even if the connection is good. "

you can fix it by adding:

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

this will fix the problem with the "keep alive" connections.